# pandas groupby filter, drop some group

Tags: python, pandas

I have groupby object

```
grouped = df.groupby('name')
for k,group in grouped:    
    print group
```

there are 3 groups **bar**, **foo** and **foobar**

```
  name  time  
2  bar     5  
3  bar     6  


  name  time  
0  foo     5  
1  foo     2  

  name      time  
4  foobar     20  
5  foobar     1
```

I need to filter these groups and drop all groups which have no time greater than 5.
In my example the group foo should be dropped.
I am trying to do it with function **filter()**

```
grouped.filter(lambda x: (x.max()['time']>5))
```

but the x is obviously not only the group in dataframe format.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your final line of code really should have a `>5` rather than `>20`, you would do something similar to:

```
grouped.filter(lambda x: (x.time > 5).any())
```

As you correctly spotted `x` is actually a `DataFrame` for all indices where the `name` column matches the key you have in `k` in your for-loop.

So you want to filter based on if there are any times larger than 5 in the time-column you do the above `(x.time > 5).any()` to test it.

Comment: The result is the dataframe, so I have to do again groupby('name'), am I right? grouped.filter(lambda x: (x.time>5).any()).groupby('name')

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used to python, numpy or pandas yet. But I was investigating a solution to a similar problem, so let me report my answers by taking this question as an example.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['name'] = ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'foobar', 'foobar']
df['time'] = [5, 2, 5, 6, 20, 1]

grouped = df.groupby('name')
for k, group in grouped:
    print(group)
```

#### My Answer 1:

```
indexes_should_drop = grouped.filter(lambda x: (x['time'].max() <= 5)).index
result1 = df.drop(index=indexes_should_drop)
```

#### My Answer 2:

```
filter_time_max = grouped['time'].max() > 5
groups_should_keep = filter_time_max.loc[filter_time_max].index
result2 = df.loc[df['name'].isin(groups_should_keep)]
```

#### My Answer 3:

```
filter_time_max = grouped['time'].max() <= 5
groups_should_drop = filter_time_max.loc[filter_time_max].index
result3 = df.drop(df[df['name'].isin(groups_should_drop)].index)
```

#### Results

```
    name    time
2   bar     5
3   bar     6
4   foobar  20
5   foobar  1
```

#### Points

My Answer1 doesn't use group names to drop groups. If you need group names, you can get them by writing: `df.loc[indexes_should_drop].name.unique()`.

`grouped['time'].max() <= 5` and `grouped.apply(lambda x: (x['time'].max() <= 5)).index` returned same results.

`filter_time_max`'s index was a group name. It could not be used as an index or label to drop as it is.

```
name
foo        True
bar       False
foobar    False
Name: time, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter a GroupBy by a condition returning a list/dict of filtered groups. e.g. return a list/dict of groups whose length >= 5.

Return a list of tuples:

```
[(name,gdf) for name,gdf in df.groupby('Declarer') if len(gdf) >= 5]
```

Return a dict:

```
{name:gdf for name,gdf in df.groupby('Declarer') if len(gdf) >= 5}
```